# Adding a bundle folder to cordova plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have added a bundle to my plugin by specifyin its path

```
<resource-file src="src/ios/MyDataModel.bundle" />
```

When I install my plugin the bundle gets copied into the `Resources` folder which I think is expected.

Inside the plugin I try to get the path to that bundle by doing

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyDataModel" ofType:@"bundle"];
```

However, bundlePath is set to `nil` and I cant figure out why. What am I missing here?

Comment: This worked fine for me. The only difference is that I call `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"bundle" inDirectory:nil]`